# Windows Media Player will not play files compressed with winLame using LAME encoding

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, lame

We have a client who cannot listen to audio files we are compressing with winLame using the LAME mp3 encoding. Anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: error code c00d119 is being returned and the client also has a screen reader JAWS installed, unsure if this could be causing issue.

Comment: What codec pack are you using?

Comment: Are the audio files on the PC or some kind of portable device  connected to the PC?

Comment: LAME is being used to compress via winLame and the files are on the client's PC after downloading them. The work fine if we don't run them through the compressor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Vista or W7

1) Go to Control Panel, Hardware and Sound, Manage Audio Devices.

2) Find your speakers in the list shown, and first make sure they have a green tick to indicate that they are the default speakers - if not, set them as default.

3) Click on the speakers to highlight them then click Properties.

4) Go to the Advanced tab, and at the bottom of this page are some checkboxes - one says "Allow Applications to have Exclusive Control" -- if this is on, then that's the problem. Turn the check OFF and click Apply.

Comment: It's on an XP machine

Comment: What are the original files that are being compressed using winlame?